# How to change first simple singleview viewController to navigation viewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I first like to load simple viewController which shows some option and then clicking on some button I would like to load navigationController or tabbarController depending on button click. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replace the root view controller on the window when I want to switch the views.

For example in my app I show a loading screen first then I switch the view to a login screen.

To do this you need a reference to your app delegate then you can access the window property and replace the root view controller:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];              
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = loginVC;
```

Comment: but in ios 5 i got error when i try to use first line of your answer's code block

Comment: Replace MyAppDelegate with the name of your app delegate file.  MyAppDelegate is the name of my file, yours will be different

Comment: Default for a new project is called AppDelegate. I've updated my code block

Comment: i got your intention and change accordingly to my project see my answer below but thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your simpleViewController :

```
- (IBAction) yourButtonAction:(id)sender
{
   UIViewController *Vc = [[theViewControllerYouWantToShow alloc]init];
  UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Vc];
  [self  presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
}
```

**Edit :**

you have three options to show your viewController content :

1. as the example above using `presentModalViewController:`
2. add the viewController view as a subView to the current viewController.
   in your case : `[simpleViewController.view addSubView:nav.view];`

3.or if your simple ViewController is the navigation root viewController you can push other viewControllers to its navigation stack.

Comment: i dont what to use presentModelviewController as i need to do some more process and my app need to change viewControllers many time

Comment: i first present simple viewController on that viewController's view i have three buttons on clicking the button i want to load either navigationViewController or TabBarViewController

Answer (score 1):

in appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIApplicationDelegate>delegate;
```

in appdelgate.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

in my first viewController's .h file

```
AppDelegate *myappDelegate;
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;
```

in my first viewController's .m file

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Start Button is clicked");
    mvc = [[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    myappDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    myappDelegate.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mvc];
    myappDelegate.window.rootViewController = myappDelegate.navigationController;
    [myappDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
}
```